# Starting/stopping Spring Batch jobs from 3rd party app

Tags: spring-batch

I am planning to build a web application where I'd want to start/stop Spring Batch jobs.
As far as I know when I use the Spring Batch Console theb this web app is bundled with the Spring Batch admin application (which runs the jobs) so both the Spring Batch Console and the jobs run in the same JVM so there is no problem to start/stop jobs from Spring Batch Console.

However I am planning to run the jobs from another (node.js) web application which is not in the same JVM (or in the same host).

Any hint please how to do that? What about the authentication / authorization?

Thank you!

Regards, V.

Comment: Have you checked Spring Cloud DataFlow: https://dataflow.spring.io? It provides all the features you listed here.

Comment: Cheers but it should be a separate web application if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to create REST APIs that can be used to manage your spring batch jobs.  The spring-batch-lightmin project (https://github.com/tuxdevelop/spring-batch-lightmin) could provide at least a useful reference for how to do this.  It has a concept of Remote Repository Server, which is a spring boot app that hosts spring batch jobs.  It provides a REST API layer that is then used by the client to administer the batch jobs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So there isn't a built-in feature in Spring Batch Admin Service to be called from an external service?

Comment: The original spring batch admin project did have rest apis as well.  i forked that project and modified it to work with spring boot, but didn't implement the rest apis as I didn't need them (see https://github.com/httpants/spring-batch-admin)

Comment: Thanks again! You mentioned that the original Spring Batch has REST api but sadly I didn't find it. Did I misinterpret something? Thanks!

Comment: If I were you i would implement RESTControllers that expose the same methods as the JobController and JobExecutionController (see https://github.com/httpants/spring-batch-admin/tree/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/admin/web), then add whatever security you want (oauth2.0) to those REST APIs.

Comment: Thanks again! Probably I should do that. If you posted this comment as a solution then I am happy to accept it. Thank you!